# In UML, does the passing of an object as a parameter to instantiate another object constitute (by itself) usage of the first?

Tags: c++, dependencies, uml, communication, instantiation

I am trying to represent the following situation, relating to the construction of a GUI in C++ , using UML 2:

- A have a program written in C++ that has a `MainWindow` class which instantiates a `GameManagementInterfacePanel` class during construction.
- The constructor of `MainWindow` requires, as a parameter, a reference to a `GameManager` object.
- That `GameManager` referenced is the one passed through to the `GameManagementInterfacePanel` constructor.
- The interface of the `GameManager` object is never exercised by `MainWindow`.  Although I have not yet done so, I believe the `GameManager` object could (should!) be forward declared (in C++).

My question is whether, **in the context of UML**, the `MainWindow` class currently **uses** or even **depends** on the `GameManager` class?

According to the glossary of the 2nd edition of the UML reference manual, "usage" is defined as:

> A dependency in which one element (the client) requires the presence of another element (the supplier) for its correct functioning or implementation.

In the *Terms and Concepts* section of **The UML User Guide (Second Edition)**, the function of the "use" dependency stereotype is defined as follows:

> Specifies that the semantics of the source element depends on the semantics of the public part of the target

The first description seems to indicate that it should be shown as a usage dependency (with the `<<use>>` stereotype).  The second seems less clear-cut to me, since `MainWindow` does not depend on the "public part" of `GameManager`.

Perhaps I do not have the mental powers necessary to work this one out (what is correct according to the UML documentation).  Either that or I'm ignorant of something.

I feel like I want to show the dependency in my particular class diagram, but I'm not sure if others would think it helps comprehension or just complicates the diagram.  I will likely keep showing it, because, to me, it aids comprehension and communication for my purposes (which is what it's all about in the end).

I'm just curious as to what other people think is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, reading and internal reflection and discussion, I believe I have come to a satisfactory answer to this question.  I ramble a bit but I really want to document this!

A **usage dependency** (`<<use>>`) relationship, and **not a normal dependency**, is what I should be using to specify the relationship between the `MainWindow` and `GameManager` classes.

Originally, I wasn't sure because of the (seemingly) conflicting information in the texts quoted in the question.  (This was quite concerning since both texts were written by Booch, Rumbaugh and Jacobson!).

After reading Tony's question, I started to think that I had just been blind to the reality that I should just use dependency.  Then I followed the link to source material provided by [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174910/tony-rad) and reading the definition of "Dependency" a few times, it was clear that that relationship just doesn't sit right in this case.

> ...changes to one model element ... can cause changes in another model element...

Apart from changing the name of the `GameManager` class, altering it will not affect `MainWindow`.

(This source is interesting because, to me at least, it's not strictly a UML reference since it's just a help page for an IBM product.  As it turns out, that doesn't matter because it's virtually the same as the one from the reference manual.)

Looking through that list, one eventually comes to the "Usage" relationship

> A usage relationship is a dependency relationship in which one model element requires the presence of another model element (or set of model elements) for its full implementation or operation.

This is a much better description of the situation and it was hard not to get the feeling this was the way to go.  I felt like the conflict between the User Manual and reference was becoming more and more irrelevant.

Then I started wondering because I remembered something curious about Visual Paradigm for UML; It has two tools to create a usage dependencies:

[image]

(One can choose the `Dependency` tool and then add a `<<use>>` stereotype.)

Why is that odd one might ask? Well now I'm wondering, is a usage dependency actually a direct specialisation of a relationship or a dependency relationship?  Was it's meaning quite separate from straight dependency? Either way, it's important enough to get its own tool in VP.

Further digging in the reference manual revealed that there was nothing particularly special about the usage dependency apart from the fact that it is emphasised.

I finally decided to check [the latest UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF/) from OMG to try and put the whole thing to rest.  The final piece of evidence to put the conclusion beyond doubt were the description and semantics specified for the two relationships from sections 7.3.12 and 7.3.54.

**Dependency:**
*Semantics*

> ... the modification of the supplier may impact the client model elements. A dependency implies the semantics of the client(sic?) is not complete without the supplier.

**Usage:**
*Description*

> A usage is a relationship in which one element requires another element (or set of elements) for its full implementation or operation.  In the metamodel, a Usage is a Dependency in which the client requires *the presence* of the supplier.

*Semantics*

> The usage dependency does not specify how the client uses the supplier other than the fact that the supplier is used by the definition of implementation of the client.

Each of these statements is congruent with the conclusion that Usage is the appropriate concept for the situation presented in the question.

Finally, giving a hint as to the spirit in which usage dependencies should be used, is the following statement from the reference manual (p64):

(with regard to the need for usage dependency relationships:

> Frequently, this comes from implementation concerns, such as compiler requirements that the *definition* of one class is needed to compile another class.

Taking all this together leads to the conclusion that a usage dependency is a *weaker* form of dependency than straight dependency, but that's somewhat subjective.

Phew!

Answer (score 1):

Well Mike,

While you are drawing or reading any UML diagram first you have should have "solid purpose".

It is not something "you feel like it" or "some other like it".

You and your "team" is the only guys that decide that showing dependency will help your  purpose[ which motivates why you drawing diagram] or it will complicate diagram.

You have "exactly mental power" to decide this, because you are writing this softaware. All UML artifacts are for helping you while writing software.

But as a rule:

If you find yourself in a situation like

- should I show this or not
- oh should I use extend or include(or any other uml notation)
- well, is this correct UML notation

and while drawing your diagram  and you spend more than 15 minutes on those things, that means you are not thinking on your project[ which drawing UML diagram pupose should be], you are making **UML Masturbation...**

As all mens do this in his/her early or maybe later ages, and sometimes it is good, it should not be a lifestyle...

As a result be pragmatic...Focus on value, not on "picture drawing"...

I hope i can make myself clear...

Comment: I understand your point but I think I made my actual position pretty clear in my second last paragraph.  I like using it, but I would like to know if others agree or not.  This is a Q&A site and I'm asking people ifthey think it's good or bad and why.  My "solid purpose" btw is to indicate the dependencies within my program.  The first iteration of my diagrams were finished long ago.  I'm now looking at revising them having completed a first iteration of the implementation.  I find the minutes I spend on UML models thinking about the program saves a lot of time refactoring code later btw.

Comment: Mike,the answer depends on your context. How can other guys know your specific context...So if spending on UML daigrams more time and this gives you "valu", then do it...UML is not "religion".It is simple " a notation". You do not need " a father"  which will agree or not agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood:

- MainWindow are not using GameManager but depends on it
- MainWindow not only uses GameManagementInterfacePanel but also create it (so you can use the 
  create stereotype)
- I can't tell if GameManagementInterfacePanel uses GameManager but it at least depends on it.

In general any relationship between an element A and an element B is a dependency if changing B will provoke a change to A:

> "A dependency relationship indicates that changes to one model element
>   (the supplier or independent model element) can cause changes in
>   another model element (the client or dependent model element). The
>   supplier model element is independent because a change in the client
>   does not affect it. The client model element depends on the supplier
>   because a change to the supplier affects the client.".
>   ([source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/rreltyp.html))

It is possible to add more informations about the relationship type because you can have several types of dependency: << use >> (if A is using the public interface of B), << instantiate >> (if A instantiate B), << bind >> (if A data are bound to B data), etc... 
It is also possible to add others stereotype beyond the [UML standard profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465146.aspx#L2) to specialize the A --> B dependency relationship with some other semantic information.

So, IMO, yes it is useful to communicate also this information to the reader of your diagram. For example with the following relationships:

- MainWindow --> GameManager (simple dependency, but you can also write MainWindow -- import -> GameManager for example if you want to highlight this particular relation to the reader)
- MainWindow --<< create >>--> GameManagementInterfacePanel
- GameManagementInterfacePanel --<< use? >>--> GameManager

Comment: Thanks for your helpful post Tony.  My problem wasn't so much that I didn't know about other stereotypes, it was more about which was the best to use.  I should have pointed out that I'm already using `<<instatiation>>` where appropriate.  Also, I'm not sure if one can (strictly) use `<<import>>` on classifiers other than packages.  Might be something to check out.